# BroadcastReceiver SharedPreferences just not reliable

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I have an Android broadcast receiver (using Eclipse if it matters) that is started by a service that is suppose to check if an online data version is updated. If so, I want to trigger a notification in the notification bar.

Everything seems to work OK, however, the results it gets from SharedPreferences are just not reliable. The broadcast receiver is suppose to get the current value stored in the SharedPreferences and compare it to a value it gets from a web url. If it compares the value and sees an update has been made (i.e. the value in at the url is greater than the stored value) it triggers a notification and also updates the value stored in the SharedPreferences. The broadcast receiver checks this update once per day and this only is intended to notify the users, nothing more.

The code I am using to do this seems to work. But here and there, it pulls a default value from the SharedPreferences and triggers an update notification even though nothing has changed.

I realize that I may be trying to do too much in the onReceive of the broadcast receiver, however I am very confused on how to fire an activity to do the work from the broadcastreceiver.

Does anyone have any code examples of the best way to implement this? I have searched and searched but I cannot seem to find clear steps to do this either way. Here is what I have:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static JSONArray myJArray2;
    public static InputStream is = null;
    public static final String URL_DatabaseVersion = "http://www.mysite.com/mobile/version.php";
    public static NotificationManager nm;
    public static Boolean updated = false;
    public static int latestVersion = 0;
    public static int internalVersion = 2;

    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        updated = false;
        SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        internalVersion = settings.getInt("dataversion", 1); 

        InputStream is = null;
        String result = "";
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("",""));

        try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL_DatabaseVersion);
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs)); 
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
        }catch(Exception e){
        }

        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result=sb.toString();
        }catch(Exception e){
        }

        try{
            JSONArray myJArray = new JSONArray(result);
            myJArray2 = myJArray;
        }catch(JSONException e){
        }     

        int mode = Activity.MODE_PRIVATE;
        SharedPreferences mySharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefsFile",mode);           
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mySharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putInt ("dataversion", latestVersion);
        editor.commit();

        if (!Arrays.asList(myJArray2).contains(null))   
        {
            try{
                for(int i=0;i<myJArray2.length();i++)
                {
                    JSONObject json_data = myJArray2.getJSONObject(i);
                    latestVersion = json_data.getInt("title");

                    if (internalVersion < latestVersion)
                    {
                        updated = true;
                    } 
                    else
                    {
                        updated = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {}
            finally
            {}
        }
        else
        {
            updated = false;
        }

        if (updated)
        {
            nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            CharSequence from = "Database Updated";
            CharSequence message = "I: " + internalVersion + " L: " + latestVersion + "Click to open.";
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(), 0);
            Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, "Database Updated", System.currentTimeMillis());
            notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, from, message, contentIntent);
            nm.notify(1, notif);
        }
    }
}
```

Yes, I am probably trying to do way too much in a BroadcastReceiver and that might be causing the issue, however I cannot figure out how to do this any other way. When I log the results of this code, the first time through it works great. Second time through the internalVersion comes up 0. The value it gets from the URL is ALWAYS correct, it is the internalVersion, the one it pulls from SharedPreferences which is wrong many times.

Any thoughts? Sorry so long. Thanks.

Corey

Comment: Not sure if it'd fix your problem, but I'd do pretty much all of this work in a `Service`. There's no obvious reason I can see to do this in a `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: That may be true, but I am not sure how to set it up to do this. Do I call a service from the onReceive of the broadcastcastreceiver? Not sure how to get the 24 hour repeating check each time even if user is not currently interacting with the app.???

Comment: Yeah, you can start the `Service` from the `BroadcastReceiver`.

Answer (score 2):

`SharedPreference.Editor.commit()` is a blocking call. This will take time and could result in likely ANRs.

Use `apply()` on API 9 and up and thread this off before while storing the expected value locally on older API versions, move this code to a service, and log your exceptions so you can debug appropriately for race conditions like this.

Answer (score 0):

You should write/commit your changes only when you realize, something has changed - that is in the "if (updated)" branch. And you should not use static members but commit the value you read from the server.

Say your Receiver has been started anew (in a **new** process). In this case static values are starting with their initial values, so latestversion is "0". You commit this value.

Next run you read the "0". Now internalversion is lower than the server version - even if no change has happened.

Comment: So, I would end up with a service setting an alarm receiver that calls another service?

Comment: OK, I have implemented the above now in a service that is called from the Alarm Receiver and it seems to work great. Thanks for the guidance. One question though, I seem to get a momentary screen flicker when the service runs, and if I don't use finish() at the end of the code, the service displays a blank white screen and stays active. Any suggestions?

Comment: Services don't display screens - that's what Activities are for (and only Activities have the finish() method). Could you post some code?

Comment: BTW: Your comments belong to the comments under the question above, since they have nothing to do with this answer.   The answer was just explaining why your code was unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

Try by using:

```
 int mode = Context.MODE_PRIVATE;
```

instead of

```
 int mode = Activity.MODE_PRIVATE;
```

It'll start saving values in **SharedPreferences**.